# when porting android 2.2 application on android1.6 platform

Tags: android

I have developed an application on android2.2. when I install this application on actual device having android1.6 then it gives me error "java.lang.string" when click on a button.
does somebody has any idea what may be the cause and how to eradic

Thanks
Parvendra

Comment: describe the entire error and post your logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Android 1.6 doesn't support some functions/methods available for Android 2.2 To see them just recompile your project under API SDK 3 - and you'll see what gives you mentioned exception

Comment: Version 3 is for 1.5. Version 4 is for 1.6. http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html